# Implementing a Changing Racetrack into My Java Driver

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create a racetrack which looks like this:

```
 A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|AB|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

where A is a car and B is another car.

they will need to progress along the racetrack in a manner like this using pre-determined speeds and fuel consumption rates:

```
 A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  |  |  |A |  |  |  |  |  | B|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------



 A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |A |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |B |  |  |  |  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In my main method driver (the controller for my racing game), I have the racetrack output showing for the start of the race:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    System.out.println(" A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("|VP|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");



}
```

But I have no idea how I will update the positions of the cars with successive rounds of the race. Should this racetrack drawing be implemented as an array? using `System.out.print("");` creates a static racetrack.

Comment: So you can print a pretty ASCII picture but have not even thought about the data structures etc you need to solve the problem.

Comment: It could be implemented as an array, but it doesn't have to be. You have two cars, and each car has a position (A-Y, though likely 0-24 internally). To print the track, print lines 1 and 2, the use a loop over positions 0-24 and print spaces or car letters as appropriate, and finally print line 4.

Comment: you could do what @Andreas suggested, it's certainly a more flexible design; however, unless you think the functionality is gonna change much this design is simpler and simplicity wins when its sufficient. All that said, you should store the strings that you need to work with into variables not just have them hard coded in a print statement.

Comment: @ScaryWombat  Didn't ingore, was away from computer. Accepted your answer.

Comment: @Rosifr My apologies to you then. Thanks for the acceptance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if car A is at position 5, you can print 4 `|` before printing the car and then print the rest

something like

```
    int len = 20;
    String trackBit = "| ";
    int pos = 5;

    for (int x = 0; x < len; x++) {
        if (x == pos) {
          System.out.print("|A");
        }
        else {
          System.out.print(trackBit);
        }
    }
```

Comment: A bit oversimplified, given that OP has two cars to show, and `trackBit` should be `"|  "` with two spaces, space 1 for car A, and space 2 for car B.

Comment: @Andreas very very simplified - even - but maybe a bit useful to the OP

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution

```
public class RacingGame {

    private static final String track = "|VP|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |";

    public static void PrintTrack(int charA, int charB) {
        StringBuilder modifiedTrack = new StringBuilder(track);
        int indexA = charA*3-1;
        int indexB = charB*3-1;
        if(indexA == indexB) indexB--;
        modifiedTrack.replace(indexA, indexA, "A");
        modifiedTrack.replace(indexB, indexB, "B");

        System.out.println(" A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(modifiedTrack);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: how is this used/called?

Comment: You call it with the position of the cars. @Rosifr said there is some logic on calculating the position of the cars, you call that and then call this with the output.